# socket.send() Exception when using thread and nest_asyncio

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord rich presence inside a bot, I got it working, but when I use `.presence off` to turn it off, it will begin to sent `socket.send() raised exception.` after about 3 minutes, I am wondering what would be causing it and how would I fix it.

**Temporary fix:**
I just ended up rebooting the script after I turn it off, but if you have a better way let me know.

here is the short version of the code:

```python
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

from pypresence import Presence

import discord
import asyncio
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from threading import Thread

import json
import os
import time

def configgg():
    paath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + r"\data\config.json"
    if os.path.exists(paath):
        with open(paath) as cock:
            data = json.load(cock)
            global __token__
            __token__ =data['token']
            global __prefix__
            __prefix__ =data['prefix']

configgg()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=__prefix__, self_bot=True, case_insensitive=True)


def actualpresence():
    global presence
    loopie = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    perse = Presence('client id', loop=loopie)

    perse.connect()

    buttons = [{"label": "These buttons are pretty cool", "url": "https://pornhub.com"}]

    perse.update(state="Buttons test", buttons=buttons)

    while True:
        if presence is False:
            perse.close()
        time.sleep(30)


@bot.command()
async def presence(icy, toggle='on'):
    global presence
    if 'on' in toggle or 'true' in toggle:
        presence = True
        thread = Thread(target=actualpresence)
        thread.start()
    if 'off' in toggle or 'false' in toggle:
        presence = False

bot.run(__token__, bot=False)
```